# MongoDB insert - uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list :

Tags: mongodb

```
db.restaurants.insert( "address": 
                        [
                          {
                            "building": "1007",
                            "coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
                            "street": "Morris Park Ave",
                            "zipcode": "10462"
                          }
                        ]
                     )
```

Error: `uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list :`

What is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `{` bracket, you can follow [https://docs.mongodb.com](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/)

```
db.restaurants.insert(
  { 
    "address": 
    [
      {
        "building": "1007",
        "coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
        "street": "Morris Park Ave",
        "zipcode": "10462"
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces at start and end are missing. Please do some reasearch before posting the question

```
 db.restaurants.insert( {"address": 
                            [
                              {
                                "building": "1007",
                                "coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
                                "street": "Morris Park Ave",
                                "zipcode": "10462"
                              }
                            ]
                    }
```